# How do I access this in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I've followed the instructions stated [here](https://github.com/has-lv/ipbwi).

However, when I attempt to access it in my controller, I get an error:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\IPBWI' not found @ line 12

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Haslv\Ipbwi;

  MyController extends Controller {

    public function index() {

      $member_info = IPBWI::member()->info(); //line 12
      //etc

    }    
}
```

I understand what's wrong but I don't understand how do to correctly reference it.

Could you help me out?

Comment: Did you add Facade and Service provider? Also, try to run `composer dumpauto`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yes, I've added them and done the dump auto load command and also the config publish command as stated on the readme page

Comment: Try also to clear all cache: `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: Thanks Alexey, I ran the command but no change.

Comment: Have you tried using case-sensitive namespaces? Changing IPBWI::member() to Ipbwi::member() . Depending on which system you run your code, casing can cause these issues.

Comment: @toxels87 Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that but it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got this, but I would take it out:

```
use Haslv\Ipbwi;
```

If you want to use Laravel's facade and you followed the instructions on the github page, then you should add this to the top of your controller:

```
use IPBWI;
```

This is also case-sensitive so make sure that it matches the case in this line of code in your `config/app.php` file:

```
'IPBWI' => 'Haslv\Ipbwi\Facade',
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to move your namespace and use statement above the class declaration.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Haslv\Ipbwi;

class MyController extends Controller {
    // controller code
}
```

Comment: It was a Typo and I had already edited my post before you submitted this answer I think.